# Schengen visa help! Two insurance, different dates?

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, insurance

I will be participating in a student conference in Germany. I will need a visa for this, hence a need for travel insurance.

The organization that invited me already provided insurance. However, the date of my departure from my country (so this is my arrival to Germany) and the date on the travel insurance is different by one day. I plan on buying a one or two day insurance that does not coincide with the insurance they already provided.

Will it be okay to have two travel insurances but of different dates?

Comment: What kind of insurance are they providing?

Comment: If your insurance does not cover during the travel date(s), they will deny you a visa.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid they provided a travel insurance that satisfies the embassy's requirements. Problem is my travel to Germany will take at least or more than a day so I have to depart a day before. However, the insurance they will provide starts on the first day of the conference. :)

Comment: @pbu that's why I'm asking if I can buy another insurance to add so my whole travel will be covered.

Comment: @Knightingale The insurance cover will start at the time you cross to international terminal after immigration. Further travel insurance in india is only valid if purchasined in india before leaving the country.

Answer (score 1):

Generally there is a problem with travel insurance that doesn't match the travel dates. I would suggest checking what the specific policy says, or ask to add days to the one you already have. 
Mixing policies is not a good idea.

Comment: Why is mixing not a good idea? Provided the traveller is covered for the entirity of their travel (and they should check - many insurers do not cover travel that has begun before the start ot the policy) why sould it matter?

Comment: @YTraveler Thank you for your answer. I plan to add another insurance wherein the dates do not coincide or get mixed up. Like one for April 5 and another for the April 6-10. April 5 is simply for the departure date. I don't think I can change it since it's already paid by the organization.... :(

Answer (score 0):

The German embassy page, says this regarding the travel insurance policy for schengen visas:

http://www.india.diplo.de/contentblob/4545450/Daten/5759751/InsuranceList.pdf

> Visa applicants for a Schengen visa for one or two entries shall prove
>   that they are in possession of adequate and valid travel medical
>   insurance to cover any expenses which might arise in connection with
>   repatriation for medical reasons, urgent medical attention and/or
>   emergency hospital treatment or death, during their stay(s) on the
>   territory of the Schengen States.
>
> ---
>
> Visa applicants for a uniform visa for more than two entries (multiple
>   entries) shall prove that they are in possession of adequate and valid
>   travel medical insurance covering the period of their first intended
>   visit. In addition, such applicants shall sign the statement, set out
>   in the application form , declaring that they are aware of the need to
>   be in possession of travel medical insurance for subsequent stays. The
>   insurance shall be valid throughout the territory of the Schengen
>   States and cover the entire period of the person’s intended stay or
>   transit. **The minimum coverage shall be EUR 30 000. Applicants shall,
>   in principle, take out insurance in their country of residence. Where
>   this is not possible, they shall seek to obtain insurance in any other
>   country.** When assessing whether the insurance cover is adequate,
>   consulates  shall ascertain whether claims against the insurance
>   company would be recoverable in a Schengen State